# Django Generic Views Usage

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I just imported generic views successfully and here comes the problem when I want to use them in views the server just gives an error directed to "." (period) in generic.ListView...

Here is the code I am currently working on.

```
def IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'question_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was very idiotic error. I just was defining traditional views with "def" i.e functions while generic views takes a view (__.as_view()) if that is a class. So by just replacing the def with class I successfully evaded the Error

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your view with `def`, change it to `class`,

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
```

Generic views are classes, which needs to be inherited.